# Solr : Path for the config files in embedded zookeeper

Tags: database, solr, embedded, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am using solr-6.0.0

Using the cloud example, 
I started solr in cloud mode using the following commands

```
bin/solr start -cloud -p 8983 -s "example/cloud/node1/solr"
bin/solr start -cloud -p 7574 -s "example/cloud/node2/solr" -z localhost:9983
```

I would like to index data from my database. Had it been stand-alone mode I would have edited the **managed-schema** and **solrconfig.xml** files accordingly. But for cloud-mode I cannot find those files.

According to the docs :

> Note that the SolrCloud example does not include a conf directory for
>   each Solr Core (so there is no solrconfig.xml or Schema file). This is
>   because the configuration files usually found in the conf directory
>   are stored in ZooKeeper so they can be propagated across the cluster.

So where can I edit those files or do I need to upload a new set of config files and override the already uploaded ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in the docs:
See the section : **Uploading configs using zkcli or SolrJ**
at [Uploading configs using zkcli](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+ZooKeeper+to+Manage+Configuration+Files)

You can do something like this to push a file :

```
zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd putfile /solr.xml /path/to/solr.xml
```

and something like this to upload the config files:

```
./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:9983 -cmd upconfig -confname <conf-name> -confdir <path-of-the-local-conf-dir>
```

Comment: how do you refer the solr.xml from zookeeper when starting a node?